# ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' rom Build/RevisionNumber.rb:4:in `<main>'

Tags: objective-c, ruby, swift, xcode

I have installed my project in new Mac that I bought, but when I run the project I get this error, I have searched a lot in internet but I couldn't find any solution, any help appreciate.

Here is the error:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- plist (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from Build/RevisionNumber.rb:4:in `'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: What build scripts have you got in your project? Looks like you have something that is using the ruby `plist` gem (directly or indirectly) and it's not installed. You'll need to figure out what your ruby dependencies are and install them

Comment: Thanks Paul,  in my build I have this and I don't know how install them:  require "rubygems"
require "plist"

Comment: The simplest thing to get you running would be `sudo gem install plist`

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, it resolved the issue :) Really thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have something that is using the ruby plist gem (directly or indirectly) and it's not installed. You'll need to figure out what your ruby dependencies are and install them.

The simplest thing to get you running would be `sudo gem install plist`